# How to make header section with menu appear, no matter where I scroll to vertically on the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a profile site which is currently hosted on Github pages. I incorporated Bootstrap and it's responsive. I have a header section which contains the navbar menu.

However, my current issue is, on either the desktop or on mobile, when I click any of the nav bar menu links and get taken to the target section, I will have to scroll back up to the header section in order to see the menu and click on another link of choice.

I want to implement a CSS animation, JavaScript or JQuery function or animation that will make it possible for the header and the menu to be visible for clicking even when I scroll away from the top of the page where it is domiciled.

In other words, when I click on the **Strengths** link and get taken to the **Strengths** section, I want to be able to touch the screen at that location (on Mobile) or click/scroll/hover (on Desktop), and have the menu appear again for clicking. Instead of scrolling all the way to the top just to click on another link.

```
ATTEMPTS

i have tried the following:


`
`$(document).on("keypress", function(){
    $(".header").css("display", "block");
})


$(document).on("touchstart", function(){
    $(".header").css("display", "block");
})


$(document).on("touchstart", function(){
    $(".header").hide();
})



$(document).on("keypress", function(){
    $(".header").show();
})`
`




But have not achieved the exact objective.

WHAT I EXPECT

When I click on a link of the menu and get taken to the section I have clicked for, I want to be able to touch the screen (on Mobile) or click/hover/scroll (on Desktop) and have my menu appear once again at this current location. 

This way, I can always have access to the nav menu at every location/section I am on the page at every given time. 


Kindly help on where I'm getting it wrong and what I need to do.

Thank you.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can not use a [Bootstrap fixed-top navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#placement)?

Comment: `position: sticky;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) perhaps?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to upgrade to Bootstrap 5 and place the menu links on an [Offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/offcanvas/#live-demo) that can slide in regardless of where the user is on the page.

Comment: @Yogi Thanks. I'd tried fixed position using plain CSS & now with Bootstrap fixed-top. But the problem I encountered in both situations is, the moment position is set to fixed or Bootstrap fixed-top is set, the header bar (with the entire navbar menu) will start to mask some content on the page.

Essentially & especially on mobile, when you click/tap on the navbar-toggler button, the menu collapses & remains collapsed forever. Thereby, covering contents on the page. But when removed, the contents becomes visible as they ought to be even with the collapsed menu. By the way, it's Bootstrap 5

Comment: Hi, @Yogi. The Offcanvas option seems like a good idea. It works as I would want the header/menu to work. However, seeing it on Bootstrap page, it appears from the examples there, that you have to click on a button to have the header/menu slide in, be it from the top, right or left.

Is it possible to have it slide in automatically or when I tap on any part of the page (on Mobile screen), bearing in mind that the normal flow of the page should be intact and that it should not mask any content on the page?

I saw a menu style I like on this site (http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/#/profile)

Comment: @UltimateKaycee - Yes, you can do that too by making a thin vertical button on the side. I created this simple example to get you started:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e297cdwy/)

Comment: @UltimateKaycee - You can also do the menu like in the link using a Bootstrap list group with helper classes that fix it to the side of the page.  Yet, if you are worried about covering page content then the Offcanvas would be a better choice.

Comment: @Yogi, I tried the OffCanvas option & to a reasonable extent, it worked as I liked. But has few drawbacks.

1. The header became surrounded with a white background unlike before.

2. When you click/tap on the body (I used body element as the click bait) the menu appears but will be dimmed, you'll to click the second time to brighten, then the third to take it away.

3. Most importantly, on mobile, the navbar toggle would no longer work as it would no longer expand to show the rest of the menu items.

kindly look at the page here: 

https://ultimatekaycee.github.io/ultimatekaycee/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks a lot. I have tried CSS position but it obstructed contents on the page and didn't quite work as flexibly as I wanted.

KIndly look at the page here.

https://ultimatekaycee.github.io/ultimatekaycee/

How can I implement the hanging menu here on this other link below?

http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/#/contact

Thanks